# Who is the U.S. official with the highest position within the U.S. government who has dual citizenship?

Tags: united-states, law, government, citizenship

Who is the U.S. official with the highest position within the U.S. government who has dual citizenship? I was thinking of Arnold Schwarzenegger, but I am not sure if he's the highest ranked, and I am not sure if he's still an Austrian citizen.

> Arnold Alois Schwarzenegger (born July 30, 1947) is an Austrian and
> American actor, businessman, filmmaker, former politician, and former
> professional bodybuilder best known for his roles in high-profile
> action movies. He served as the 38th governor of California from 2003
> to 2011 and was among Time magazine's 100 most influential people in
> the world in 2004 and 2007.[5][6]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold_Schwarzenegger

Comment: To address the unceertainty regarding Arnold Schwarzenegger - yes, he did indeed hold a dual citizenship during his term as Governor. E.g. a (German language) newspaper comment in "Wiener Zeitung" from that time mentioning this fact (and discussing whether he might loose the Austrian citizenship for his actions as American politician): https://www.wienerzeitung.at/h/burger-arnold-aus-mit-doppelt

Comment: @Hulk a state governor is not an official of the United States.  But he was a [Chairman of the President's Council on Physical Fitness and Sports](https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/documents/statement-the-appointment-arnold-schwarzenegger-chairman-the-presidents-council-physical) in 1990.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

"Highest position" is somewhat arbitrary (is the Speaker of the House higher ranking than the Attorney General?) so I'll go by the [presidential line of succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_line_of_succession).

**Secretary of Energy [Jennifer Granholm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_Granholm)** was born in Vancouver and became an American citizen in 1980. In [this 2010 interview on Fox News](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/transcript-fox-news-sunday-interview-on-future-of-gop) she claims to have dual citizenship.

Additionally, Secretary of the Interior Deb Haaland is an enrolled member of the [Laguna Pueblo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguna_Pueblo), a federally recognized tribe. This makes her a citizen of that tribe as well, although that is probably not the dual citizenship you refer to. If you count her she would be higher ranking.

Secretary of Homeland Security [Alejandro Mayorkas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alejandro_Mayorkas) also became a US citizen later in life but I haven't found any indication that he still holds Cuban citizenship. Given the fact that his family came to the US after the revolution when he was just one year old, probably not.

Comment: These are good finds! I was curious about this a few months ago, and could find very few instances of dual citizenship in U.S. Federal government.

Comment: It should be pointed out that in the event of a naturalized U.S. Citizen in the Cabinet, they are ineligible for the office of president, even if they are the next in line due to chain of succession, which if it gets down to cabinet secretaries, Granholm would be the highest by the definition (federal tribal Citizens are U.S. Citizens) followed by Mayorkas.  As discussed elsewhere, theoretically, nothing prevents the President of the United States from having dual citizenship, so long as their U.S. Citizenship is birth right and not naturalized citizenship.

Comment: Additionally, the Constitution has an explicit carve out for those who were not birthright citizens but were birthright citizens their place of birth's legal entry into the United States as a territory of the United States but this doesn't apply to anyone with a pulse at time of writing.  It did apply to such notable presidents as George Washington and Thomas Jefferson among other Founding Father Presidents.

Comment: @hszmv " but were birthright citizens their place of birth's legal entry into the United States as a territory of the United States" --> I think it is "No Person except a natural born Citizen, or a Citizen of the United States, at the time of the Adoption of this Constitution, shall be eligible  . . ." thus allowing A. Hamilton (born in Haiti) to qualify.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Nitpick: Hamilton was born in Nevis (in the Leeward Islands/Lesser Antilles), not Haiti.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I sit [corrected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Hamilton).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica none of the founding fathers were natural born citizens'of the United States because citizenship of the United States didn't exist when they were born.  This exception didn't apply only to Hamilton but also to Washington, Jefferson, both Adamses, Jefferson, Madison, Monroe, Jackson, and Harrison, not to mention many unsuccessful candidates.

Comment: @phoog Yes it applied to many, yet IIRC, it was worded in such a way to include Hamilton and not as hszmv suggested.

Comment: @phoog,  They thought of that.  **[Article 2, Section 1 clause 5](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/article-2/section-1/clause-5/)**,  No person except a natural born citizen, **or a citizen of the United States, at the time of the adoption of this Constitution**, shall be eligible to the office of President; neither shall any person be eligible to that office who shall not have attained to the age of thirty five years, and been fourteen Years a resident within the United States.

Comment: So Washington was president of the 4 month long constitutional convention which ratified the constitution, 19 of the 74 delegates did not show up at all.   of the 55 who did show up only 30 attended the entire time.  By the time New Hampshire showed up, 2 months late,  3 New York delegates had left leaving just Alexander Hamilton (no quorum) to represent New York.  Thus, Washington wrote that the Constitution was signed by “11 states and Colonel Hamilton.”  **[see Attendance was spotty](https://www.history.com/news/7-things-you-may-not-know-about-the-constitutional-convention)**

Comment: There is a US order of precedence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_order_of_precedence

Comment: The only people other than Granholm who may have been candidates are acting labor secretary Julie Su, but my cursory flip through the Chinese/Taiwanese citizenship pages suggests she would be neither. Again, not a nationality expert but Harris may be entitled to Jamaican citizenship? But not Indiain.

Comment: Actually Becerra may be a Mexican citizen and Buttigieg *might* be entitled to Maltese citizenship, and Souter maybe Italian?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I thought about including that but when you exclude people outside the federal government and assume you are evaluating the order in the US itself (so no ambassadors), the result is the same. And if we include ambassadors they would be higher ranking than the Secretary of State, which is not true.

Answer (score 10):

I'll go with **Former Whitehouse Chief of staff to President Obama**
**[Rahm Emanuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rahm_Emanuel)**.

- **current U.S. ambassador to Japan**
- former Senior Advisor to President Clinton
- former White House Director of Political Affairs
- former Mayor of Chicago.

He holds US and Israeli citizenship.

**What does the Chief of Staff Do?**

The Chief of staff can summon other cabinet officials to the Whitehouse and give them instruction. His words are as if they came from the President. Because they do. The COS's job is to speak for the president in the executive, act for the president, schedule the president, decide which meetings to handle himself and which meetings the President should handle, and make sure all the other cabinet ministers are doing the president's will. No other Cabinet official works as closely with the President, has the same cross over dept authority.  No other Cabinet official can even meet with the President without scheduling it with his Chief of Staff first including the VP.  If the COS wants to see the President he doesn't have to schedule it, he doesn't have to go through one of the President's secretaries in his outer office, all the COS has to do is open a single door in his office and walk directly into the Oval office.

Unlike any other Cabinet official the Chief of Staff is in on every decision the President makes.  He is the President's Senior Advisor, the other 12 senior advisors to the president report to him.  He is the most senior political appointee at the White House.   In the Trump and Biden Administrations the Chief of Staff sat/sits at the head of the Cabinet table.  He sits in the situation room where some other Cabinet officials are absent.  He sits on the National Security Council too.

The Chief of staff is literally the #2 guy in any administration. Not the VP, Sec Defense, or Sec of State.

The VP job is a rather weak position.  It is as important or unimportant as the President decides.  President Kennedy famously gave Vice President Johnson no responsibility in his administration.  President Bush Jr gave Dick Cheney great responsibility in his first term and then took away much of that authority in his second term.  Typically the VP job is chosen to balance the ticket geographically or politically.  Typically the VP is chosen among the President's political rivals, and even if they aren't the VP job is generally a front runner for the party ticket one the President leaves office.  They are not necessarily trusted inside an administration, as they can have their own team, agenda, and own political interests.

The Speaker of the house and Majority Leader in the senate are as or more powerful than the COS in government perhaps.  The COS is the #2 job in the Executive.  In influence, power, authority, and importance at least while the President lives.

Comment: As someone else said, "higher position" is not very well defined. But are any of those positions really higher than Cabinet members as liste in @xyldke's answer?

Comment: Yes, White House, Chief of Staff is considered as a higher position than a Cabinet official, as he is the gate keeper between the President and all others, including Cabinet members.  This proximity and close relationship with the President some say makes him the most influential person in any administration rivaling the President himself.  Due to the President's many non-governing duties.

Comment: "Chief of Staff is considered as a higher position than a Cabinet official" by whom? First Lady or even father/brother of the President has considerable influence but would you argue it's higher than a Cabinet official? How would you quantify influence?

Comment: As the other answer suggests, there isn't a single dimension. CoS has quite a bit of power, but so do the Cabinet officials, each in theor own dominions.

Comment: @StuartF,   Who would you say is more influential?  The head of a Dept under the Executive or **[the head of the Executive Office of the President](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House_Office)**?  Given **[The Chief of staff is the most senior political appointee in the white house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House_Chief_of_Staff)**.   Cabinet officials get their power from the President.  The closest cabinet member is the Chief of Staff.   He literally is the closest,  Office next door.  He also works most closely and has broader authority than any other cabinet official.

Comment: What power does the chief of staff have to actually do stuff? Cabinet officials have a lot more power including being in the line of succession.

Comment: @JoeW The Chief of Staff's game is being able to block others from playing theirs, or to enable them.

Comment: @Therac-StandwithPalestine / JMS: the CoS may have more power than certain cabinet officials but does not have higher rank.  The CoS has soft power that is largely derived from a capacity to influence the president's agenda.  The CoS is not subject to senate confirmation.  The CoS position is not established by act of congress.  The CoS doesn't have the same level of control over congressionally appropriated budget appropriations, etc., etc.

Comment: @phoog,  come on dude, all power and authority to do anything in the executive,  meaning every dept whether  energy, state, or defense comes from the president.  The COS”s power isn’t softer than any other cabinet official’s power.  He literally is the  number two man in the executive.  His job is to see that the presidents agenda which he helped craft is followed.  It really isn’t arguable.  Saying otherwise is akin to saying the earth is flat or moon is made of cheese.  There is only one response.  “Alrighty then!”,  sigh and push back from the keyboard.

Comment: @phoog The leadership's secretaries became the de-facto rulers of nations more than once. The CoS has disproportionate power in deciding who gets on the president's schedule, and often takes meetings and makes decisions in place of the president. Since the US is a presidential republic, the CoS is basically the third most powerful official after the VP.

Comment: @Therac-StandwithPalestine that doesn’t make them one of the highest ranking officials in the country.

Comment: @JoeW If we're talking literal rank, as in paygrade, then you're right. Although at $180,000 in 2020, they're effectively at [ES-3 level](https://www.federalpay.org/ses/level-3), equivalent to an undersecretary.